# How do I sort the filenames read with Directoryinfo

Tags: c#, sorting, directoryinfo

I'd like to read folder and file names that are thrown into one list sorted to show 
For example I have a file that looks like this:

1-4999.txt

5000-9999.txt 
......

I would like to sort the data folder

```
       var endpageNext = pagenumber * 100;
        var startpageNext = endpageNext - (100 - 1);

        var lst = GetFile(startpageNext, endpageNext);
```

[**Picture  Data Folder**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fb4f1u56c4axu3i/img1.JPG)

[**Picture Visual Studio break point**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgb7jya4lzdj7y8/img2.jpg)

```
        internal List<string> GetFile(int startpagenext, int endpagenext)
    {
        var dir = DataAccessSetting.CustomerSplit;
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        var s = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
        var lstfilename = new List<string>();
        foreach (var file in s)
        {
            var fileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
            var splitNameFile = fileWithoutExtension.Split('-');

            if ((startpagenext >= int.Parse(splitNameFile[0]) && startpagenext <= int.Parse(splitNameFile[1])) || (endpagenext >= int.Parse(splitNameFile[0]) && endpagenext <= int.Parse(splitNameFile[1])))
            {
                var ppath = dir + fileWithoutExtension + ".txt";
                lstfilename.Add(ppath);
            }

        }

        return lstfilename;
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this method, with what parameters? What is the use of parameters startpagenext and endpagenext?

Comment: I find the formula of two variables that are calculated according to the number of user I , Edit Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
List<string> lstfilename = System.IO.Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Select(Path => new { 
        Path, 
        split = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path).Split('-')
    })
    .Where(x => x.split.Length == 2 && x.split.All(s => s.All(Char.IsDigit)))
    .Select(x => new { 
        x.Path, 
        Num1 = int.Parse(x.split[0]),
        Num2 = int.Parse(x.split[1]),
    })
    .Where(x => (startpagenext >= x.Num1 && startpagenext <= x.Num2) 
             || (endpagenext   >= x.Num1 && endpagenext   <= x.Num2))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Num1).ThenBy(x => x.Num2)
    .Select(x => x.Path)
    .ToList();
```